# How to fix error with cv::boundingRect in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV version 4.0.0. I am trying to stitch some images together and trim the resulting image and while I am able to stitch the images, I am not able to trim the resulting image.

My program keeps aborting with the following error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/RAR/opencv/modules/core/src/umatrix.cpp:545: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function 'UMat'
>
> Abort trap: 6

The error occurs at the line `stitched = stitched(cv::boundingRect(c));` in the code below.

```
while (cv::countNonZero(sub) > 0) {
            cv::erode(minRect, minRect, cv::Mat());  // Erode the minimum rectangular mask
            cv::subtract(minRect, thresh, sub);  // Subtract the thresholded image from the minmum rectangular mask (count if there are any non-zero pixels left)
            std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> cnts4;
            cv::findContours(minRect.clone(), cnts4, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            c = cnts4[0];
            for (auto iter = cnts4.begin(); iter != cnts4.end(); ++iter) {
                if (cv::contourArea(*iter) > cv::contourArea(c)) { // Finds the largest contour (the contour/outline of the stitched image)
                    c = *iter;
                }
            }

            stitched = stitched(cv::boundingRect(c));  // Extract the bounding box and use the bounding box coordinates to extract the final stitched images
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: print the coordinates of the bounding rectangle. It seems like those coordinates are beyond the dimensions of the `stitched` image

Comment: @shawn-mathew I printed out the coordinates of the bounding rectangle and the rows and cols in stitched, and here is what I got: `stitched: cols: 4295 rows: 2867
bounding rect[4274 x 2845 from (11, 12)]
stitched: cols: 4274 rows: 2845
bounding rect[4272 x 2843 from (12, 13)]` How can I check if the coordinates of the bounding rectangle goes beyond the dimensions of the stitched image?

Answer (score 1):

From OP's comments:

```
stitched: cols: 4295 rows: 2867 bounding rect[4274 x 2845 from (11, 12)] 
stitched: cols: 4274 rows: 2845 bounding rect[4272 x 2843 from (12, 13)]
```

In the first case, the rectangle is trying to extract a size of `(4274, 2845)` from `(11, 12)` in the `stitched` image. This means that it is taking pixels from `(11, 12)` to `(4285, 2857)`, which is within the bounds of the `stitched` image since the `stitched` image has a size of `(4295, 2867)`. **No problem**.

In the second case, the rectangle is trying to extract a size of `(4272, 2843)` from `(12, 13)` in the `stitched` image. This means that it is taking pixels from `(12, 13)` to `(4284, 2856)`, which is out of bounds of the **stitched** image since the `stitched` image has a size of `(4274, 2845)`. **Problem**.

The sub-image you are trying to extract is much bigger than the bigger image.

> (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows

The error message also indicates this. `roi` in the error message refers to the sub-image you are trying to extract using `cv::boundingRect(c)` and `m` is the `stitched` image. The coordinates of this rectangle are beyond the size of the `stitched` image.

You can test this by setting the coordinates of the rectangle manually.

You should not get an error with `stitched(cv::Rect(11, 12, cv::Size(4274, 2845)`

You will get the error with `stitched(cv::Rect(12, 13, cv::Size(4272, 2843)`

Answer (score 0):

Last iteration is the problem, as it won't find any contours.

Maybe you can try something like so :

```
int nonZeroCount = 1;
while (nonZeroCount) 
{
    cv::erode(minRect, minRect, cv::Mat());
    cv::subtract(minRect, thresh, sub);
    nonZeroCount = cv::countNonZero(sub);
    if (nonZeroCount)
    {
        std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > cnts4;
        cv::findContours(minRect.clone(), cnts4, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        c = cnts4[0];
        for (auto iter = cnts4.begin(); iter != cnts4.end(); ++iter) 
        {
            if (cv::contourArea(*iter) > cv::contourArea(c))
            {
                c = *iter;
            }
        }
        stitched = stitched(cv::boundingRect(c));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why no contours will be found in the last iteration?

Comment: I tried your code and I am still getting an exception at the `stitched = stitched(cv::boundingRect(c));` line: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/ramyaasha/opencv/modules/core/src/umatrix.cpp:545: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function 'UMat'

Abort trap: 6`